# NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function Quantlib Python

Tags: python, quantlib

I am new to QuantLib and have just installed Quantlib and Quantlib-Python. I have MS Visual Studio 2017 and 2.7.15 64 bit.

I am trying to work through the examples in Goutham Balaraman's blog (http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/quantlib-basics.html). However, I am encountering an error.

Code:

```
    # schedule object can be used to construct a list of dates such as coupon payments
    date1 = ql.Date(1, 1, 2015)
    date2 = ql.Date(1, 1, 2016)
    tenor = ql.Period(ql.Monthly)
    calendar = ql.UnitedStates
    schedule = ql.Schedule(date1, date2, tenor, calendar, ql.Following, ql.Following, ql.DateGeneration.Forward, False)
schedule 




Error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-cae31a33e500> in <module>()
      4 tenor = ql.Period(ql.Monthly)
      5 calendar = ql.UnitedStates
----> 6 schedule = ql.Schedule(date1, date2, tenor, calendar, ql.Following, ql.Following, ql.DateGeneration.Forward, False)
      7 schedule

c:\users\papu\envs\quantlib\lib\site-packages\QuantLib\QuantLib.pyc in __init__(self, *args)
   9419 
   9420     def __init__(self, *args):
-> 9421         this = _QuantLib.new_Schedule(*args)
   9422         try:
   9423             self.this.append(this)

NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_Schedule'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    Schedule::Schedule(std::vector< Date,std::allocator< Date > > const &,Calendar const &,BusinessDayConvention const,boost::optional< BusinessDayConvention >,boost::optional< Period > const,boost::optional< DateGeneration::Rule >,boost::optional< bool >,std::vector< bool,std::allocator< bool > > const &)
    Schedule::Schedule(std::vector< Date,std::allocator< Date > > const &,Calendar const &,BusinessDayConvention const,boost::optional< BusinessDayConvention >,boost::optional< Period > const,boost::optional< DateGeneration::Rule >,boost::optional< bool >)
    Schedule::Schedule(std::vector< Date,std::allocator< Date > > const &,Calendar const &,BusinessDayConvention const,boost::optional< BusinessDayConvention >,boost::optional< Period > const,boost::optional< DateGeneration::Rule >)
    Schedule::Schedule(std::vector< Date,std::allocator< Date > > const &,Calendar const &,BusinessDayConvention const,boost::optional< BusinessDayConvention >,boost::optional< Period > const)
    Schedule::Schedule(std::vector< Date,std::allocator< Date > > const &,Calendar const &,BusinessDayConvention const,boost::optional< BusinessDayConvention >)
    Schedule::Schedule(std::vector< Date,std::allocator< Date > > const &,Calendar const &,BusinessDayConvention const)
    Schedule::Schedule(std::vector< Date,std::allocator< Date > > const &,Calendar const &)
    Schedule::Schedule(std::vector< Date,std::allocator< Date > > const &)
    Schedule::Schedule(Date const &,Date const &,Period const &,Calendar const &,BusinessDayConvention,BusinessDayConvention,DateGeneration::Rule,bool,Date const &,Date const &)
    Schedule::Schedule(Date const &,Date const &,Period const &,Calendar const &,BusinessDayConvention,BusinessDayConvention,DateGeneration::Rule,bool,Date const &)
    Schedule::Schedule(Date const &,Date const &,Period const &,Calendar const &,BusinessDayConvention,BusinessDayConvention,DateGeneration::Rule,bool)
    Schedule::Schedule()
```

Any help on what is going wrong?

Comment: The method call ql.Schedule eventually calls an overloaded C++ method. What the interpreters is trying to tell you is that none of the overloaded function signatures matches your call parameters. In other words: you call it with the wrong number and/or type of parameters. These are things that sometimes change between versions of programs, which may explain that some of the examples don't work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The answer by Luigi Ballabio below solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calendar should be `ql.UnitedStates()`, not `ql.UnitedStates`. As it is now, you're passing the class itself, not an instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, still given here, since answers are properly formatted and comments aren't.

The overload that best matchs your params:

```
schedule = ql.Schedule(
    date1,
    date2,
    tenor,
    calendar,
    ql.Following,
    ql.Following,
    ql.DateGeneration.Forward,
    False
)
```

is:

```
Schedule::Schedule(
    Date const &,
    Date const &,
    Period const &,
    Calendar const &,
    BusinessDayConvention,
    BusinessDayConvention,
    DateGeneration::Rule,
    bool
)
```

Assuming ql.DataGeneration.Forward is of type DataGeneration.Rule,
unfortunately I can't see anything wrong with your code...